# jquery where's my error using .css() to scale min height to window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm writing a script to scale my hero-unit's min-height to the window height minus the header. unless its child container is is a greater height than the window. I must be off on my syntax somewhere because what i have so far is not working.

```
$(function () {

    function heroUnitHeight() {
        if( $('.hero-unit').height < $(window).height ) {
            $('.hero-unit').css("min-height", ( $(window).height() - $('header').height())  + "px");
        } else {
            $('.hero-unit').css("min-height", $('.quick-search').height());
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hero-unit').css("padding-top", ( $('.hero-unit').height() - $('.quick-search').height()) / 4  + "px");
        heroUnitHeight();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.hero-unit').css("padding-top", ( $('.hero-unit').height() - $('.quick-search').height()) / 4  + "px");
        heroUnitHeight();
    });

});
```

Comment: Remember your order of operations. `$('.hero-unit').height() - $('.quick-search').height()) / 4` is the same as `$('.hero-unit').height() - ($('.quick-search').height()) / 4)`. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in the first if-statement of the `heroUnitHeight` function you're calling height wihthout parentheses: `$('.hero-unit').height` and `$(window).height`